# Loop through an excel file, find certain cell values and write into text files

Tags: python, xlrd

I am making text files out of information from an existing excel file. Not all of the information in the excel file is supposed to be written in the text files, but I want my code to loop through the file and choose information from rows according to certain cell values.

Here is my code so far, however, when I run the code nothing happens and the text files are not generated. I do not get an error message either. Does anyone know what I am missing?

```
import xlrd
xlsfilename = 'Myexcelfile.xls'
book = xlrd.open_workbook(xlsfilename)
book.sheet_by_index(0)
number_rows = 275
number_lines = 1

for row in range(number_rows):
    for col in 1, :     #Column where the cell value decides wether or not information in the row should be added to the text file.
        value = book.sheets()[0].cell(row, col).value
        if value == 19:   #Rows where 19 is the cell value in column 1 is to be focused on.
            txtfilename = 'Mytextfile' + str(row) + '.txt'
            with open(txtfilename, "w") as f:
                d={} #Creating a dictionary to for Subject number (see later in the code)
                for line in range(number_line):
                    f.write("Subject number{1}") #The subject number should change for each row containing 19 is added to the text file.
                    f.write('Text\n')
                    f.write('Newtext'.ljust(1))
                    for col in 3,:
                        val = book.sheets()[0].cell(row, col).value
                        s1 = str(val).ljust(1)
                        f.write(s1)
                    f.write('Moretext'.ljust(1))
                    for col 9, 10:
                        val = book.sheets()[0].cell(row, col).value
                        s2 = str(val).ljust(1)
                        f.write(s2)
        else:
            pass
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!
I am working in Python3.4.1

Comment: with a debugger, do you ever observe your code getting past `if value == 19` ?

Comment: With a debugger, I get the message: "Process finished with exit code 0" (working in PyCharm), the same message I get when I run the code in the regular way. I should also add that I am quite new to python coding.

Comment: because I don't have your worksheet to test this theory on, I can only guess that, given that you are not getting exceptions, you are not getting past `if value == 19`. That could be because your sheet either does not contain any row in column 1 with a value of 19 OR because the value is actually a text "19" (in which case, you would do `value == "19"`). Also, by column 1 do you mean the first column ? Because if you mean the first column then you need to use column 0 instead.

Comment: Put a breakpoint under value 19 to see if this is actually the case. if you don't hit the breakpoint then you are not getting there.

Comment: It was a string! Can not believe I did not think about that, thank you! But I still have a problem. I want information from all of the rows that includes the string "19" to be written into the same text file, as for now, they are written in different text files. Do you have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: You are welcome, I put an answer to let you use a single file to write your data in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write all the rows that include the string "19" in column 1 into the same text file, you can do:

```
import xlrd
xlsfilename = 'Myexcelfile.xls'
book = xlrd.open_workbook(xlsfilename)
book.sheet_by_index(0)
number_rows = book.sheets()[0].nrows
number_lines = 1
column_target = 1
txtfilename = 'Mytextfile.txt'

with open(txtfilename, "w") as f:
    for row in range(number_rows):
        value = book.sheets()[0].cell(row, column_target).value
        if value == "19":   #Rows where 19 is the cell value in column 1 is to be focused on.
                d={} #Creating a dictionary to for Subject number (see later in the code)
                for line in range(number_line):
                    f.write("Subject number{1}") #The subject number should change for each row containing 19 is added to the text file.
                    f.write('Text\n')
                    f.write('Newtext'.ljust(1))
                    for col in 3,:
                        val = book.sheets()[0].cell(row, col).value
                        s1 = str(val).ljust(1)
                        f.write(s1)
                    f.write('Moretext'.ljust(1))
                    for col 9, 10:
                        val = book.sheets()[0].cell(row, col).value
                        s2 = str(val).ljust(1)
                        f.write(s2)
        else:
            pass
```

Basically, just move the file scope outside of the loop so that the same file can be reused for multiple rows.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly!
In the future I need to do the same thing I did here, but with more numbers than only 19. So I need the loop to go through the column of request and find the numbers that are the same. I want the information from the rows with the same numbers to be written into the same text files. So all of the rows with the number 20 in column 1 goes in one text file, all of the rows with the number 2 in column 1 goes in another text file etc. Do you have any idea on how I could do this?

Comment: there are different ways you can do that, one way would be to create all the various files you need separately, using `file_19 = file("file_name","w")` and put them into a `dict` like `files = {"19": file_19, "20": file_20}`. Then in your code, if you have a value == "19" you would do `files["19"].write("content\n")`. At the end of your code you would loop through the files in the dict and close the files, like: `for k in files: files[k].close()`. It's a good exercise for you to try out.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I will definitely use your advice!